# About the general solution of $x'(t)+x(t)=\int_0^{x(t)}\frac{du}{\cosh u}$

Tags: integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I wondered as curiosity about the general solution of the nonlinear ordinary differential equation  $$x'(t)+x(t)=\int_0^{x(t)}\frac{du}{\cosh u},\tag{1}$$ for $t\geq 0$. See the article of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function) or [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gudermannian.html) dedicated to the Gudermannian function.

Of couse I know using Euler's trick the solution of the homogeneous equation $x'(t)+x(t)=0$ as $Ce^{-t}$ for a real constant $C$ depending of the value $x(0)$. Or also (for real variables $C_1$ and $C_2$ we obtain the solution as a vectorial space of dimension $2$) the solution of the homogeneous equation associated to the derivative of $(1)$

$$x''(t)+x'(t)=\frac{2x(t)}{e^{x(t)}+e^{-x(t)}},\tag{2}$$
 as $x_h(t)=C_1+C_2e^{-t}$. Also I've tried to combine with facts that I know of hyperbolic functions, but I believe that it doesn't solve the problem, that is that our equation $(1)$ is nonlinear and thus is difficult, and in this exercise I believe that impossible to compute explicitely the particular solution $x_p(t)$, that I need, to express the general solution of $(1)$ using the superposition principle.

> **Question.** I want to solve $(1)$, well explicitely or well numerically. I don't know if has mathematical meaning the linearization to explore the shape of the solutions of this non-linear equation. Then I would like to refresh topics from differential equations and numerical analysis, learn more from your answer. The question is thus do calculations and reasonins to state the solution of $(1)$. **Thanks in advance.**

See the output that was calculated by [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com) from my code

`solve x'+x=gd(x)`

the plot of the solution family sampling $x(0)$. Then, what are your ideas to present the solutions of my Question?

---

**I've updated** $(2)$ since was a mistake, see the comments. We can see also that there was a mistake in my original $(2)$ using the second fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: You have not correctly converted to the second order, the right one is
$$x'+x=gd(x)$$
We know that
$$\frac{d}{dx}gd(x)=sech(x)$$
Thus
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x'+x)=sech(x)$$
$$\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}}=sech(x)\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Comment: If of course, now I see it. I'm sorr, and many thanks @KirylPesotski

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation, now I know what happened since you are using the chain rule @KirylPesotski

Comment: Maple CAS : $\left\{x(t)=\text{c1},\int_0^{x(t)} \frac{1}{2 \tan ^{-1}(\exp (a))+\text{c1}} \,
   da-t-\text{c2}=0\right\}$

Comment: I don't understand your contribution. I don't know Maple. Any case many thanks @MariuszIwaniuk I did with question with the purpose to learn and refresh thinks from numerical methods for odes.

Comment: @user243301. I only give you a solution in integral form.

Comment: I was stuck, then you are saying that it is the solution powered by Maple. Many thanks @MariuszIwaniuk it is a good hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating the integral, makes the ODE appear as
$$x'(t)+x(t)=2 \arctan \left( \tanh \left( \frac{x(t)}{2} \right) \right)=\operatorname{gd}(x(t)).$$
This equation is separable, i.e.
$$\frac{x'(t)}{\operatorname{gd}(x(t))-x(t)}=1 $$ 
Integrating both sides gives
$$\int_{t_0}^t \frac{x'(\tau)}{\operatorname{gd}(x(\tau))-x(\tau)} \mathrm{d} \tau=t-t_0.$$
Using the change of variables $u=x(\tau)$, alongside with $x(t_0)=x_0$ gives the implicit solution
$$\int_{x_0}^x \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\operatorname{gd}(u)-u}=t-t_0. $$

Comment: Many thanks also to you.

Comment: I see that you answered the question, since as you said the equation is separable and one can get directly the implicit solution. I am going to wait some days if there are more contributions, using numerical analysis, and after I should accept an answer.